# Footer overlapping part of chat in chat.stackoverflow

Tags: bug, chat

[image]
I think the image explains it all. Not sure if it's just me. The stared messages is being overlapped by the footer for some reason.

On the latest version of chrome and on Windows 10.

Comment: Well... yes? there's more stuff than there is room for, especially with that huge description; something has to give. We dismissed the idea of a scrollbar for the border, as it would get confusing - instead the single scrollbar controlls the main conversation. There *is* some code to try to help minimize the overlap, but: it can only do so much